# preg_match for <?php, <?, and/or ?>

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I'm not very familiar with regEx's and I'm trying to find a preg_match regex for searching for any of the following strings within a file and if found it will halt it.  I already have the `fopen` and `fgets` and `fclose` setup I just need to use a regex inside of a preg_match for the following php tags:

`<?php`
`<?`
`?>`

so if preg_match returns 1 than this will skip this file and not upload it.  I am using the $_FILES array to upload it via post, so I'm hoping I can use the $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] variable for this to read through the file.

Thanks for your help with this :)

**EDIT**

```
if (in_array('application/x-httpd-php', $files[$filid]['mimetypes']) && ($_FILES[$value]['type'][$n] == 'application/octet-stream' || $_FILES[$value]['type'][$n] == 'application/octetstream'))
{
    $file_extension = strtolower(substr(strrchr($_FILES[$value]['name'][$n], '.'), 1));

    if ($file_extension == 'php')
    {
        // Reading the current php file to make sure it's a PHP File.
        $fo = fopen($_FILES[$value]['tmp_name'][$n], 'rb');
        while (!feof($fo))
        {
            $fo_output = fgets($fo, 16384);

            // look for a match
            if (preg_match([REG EX HERE], $fo_output) == 1)
            {
                $php = true;
                break;
            }
        }
        fclose($fo);
    }
}
```

OK, I apologize, but actually, what I am doing is I need to find a PREG MATCH.  Because if it is a PHP FILE, I need to set the MIME TYPE to:  application/x-httpd-php within the database.  BECAUSE I'm also allowing PHP Files to be uploaded as well in certain instances.  So hopefully the code I posted above makes more sense to you all now.

Can someone please help me with a `preg_match` regex for this please?

Comment: Sounds pretty odd. Why do you need it?

Comment: So you want to reject any file that has `<?php`, `<?` or `?>` in it? Why? Just don’t handle it as PHP file.

Comment: And how do you handle it as PHP file?  The thing is I want to know if it's an actual PHP file that was uploaded...  That is I must check the inside of it, right?  They can always change the file extension, so that doesn't help me any...  ONLY way I can think of is to search within the file for `<?php`, `<?`, or `?>` strings.

Comment: You cannot know it for sure. You can find a plenty of JPEGs with such a symbol combination inside. Nobosy does that cause it's just senseless

Comment: Are you **really** sure you want to store exactly this one MIME TYPE for the PHP files?

Comment: Whys that?  Would this output the PHP onto the page?  In any case the mime type isn't used for this, as all mime types get outputted as `application/octet-stream` or `application/octetstream` anyways, unless they are image files.  This mime type is used for something else.

Comment: You can just upload files to a non-webroot directory and use another php file to download it (download.php?id=123). Just use readfile and a content-type like `application/octet-stream`. If you must use a web directory use `.htaccess` to prevent php from executing in that directory. Content sniffing has been proven time and time again not to be the the way to go.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
/(?:<\?(?!xml)|\?>)/
```

(15 chars)

Comment: No need to test for `<?php` as `<?php` will already be matched by `<?`.

Comment: Ok, so how would I change this for only `<?` and `?>` strings than?

Comment: You would simply remove the center block, leaving you with /(?:<\?|\?>)/

Comment: @Matt: yes, but that's what the OP asked

Comment: @kemp - strictly speaking, OP asked to only match PHP tags

Comment: Ouch, yeah, is there a way to match PHP Tags only?  So really, it should check for a space at the end of this or make sure that this is the only string in this...  So we should be able to derive a solution to this, as it needs to match `<?`, `<?php`, or `?>` ONLY.

Comment: So, I suppose you'll need to match `<?php` directly than as well as all of the other possible php tags, guess that's the only way.  But how?

Comment: You can discard the `xml` possibilty with a negative lookahead (edited now). If you look for PHP stuff you also have to consider `<?=`

Comment: So there's no way to make a regex for a perfect match of `<?` or `?>` or `<?php` ONLY?

Comment: Well ONLY `<?` is tricky, as it depends on what follows it. `<?$var` is PHP, `<?xml` is XML.

Comment: Sorry, after testing this approach even further, I see it doesn't work after all.  Thanks anyways, but I have decided to use another approach... arggg

Answer (score 2):

If you want to parse the file, try the following instead:

```
function containsPhp($file) {
    if(!$content = file_get_contents($file)) {
        trigger_error('Not a file');
        return false;
    }
    foreach(token_get_all($content) as $token) {
        if(is_array($token) && in_array(current($token), array(T_OPEN_TAG, T_OPEN_TAG_WITH_ECHO))) {
            return true;                
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

... besides checking for a php extension (php, php5, phtml, inc etc).

Comment: Ok, I don't know what's going on here, but I just uploaded an XML file using this approach after changing the file extension from .xml to .php.  So this doesn't work at all.

Comment: And when I upload other files, for example .zip files, I get this error about 100 times at the top of my page:  `Warning: Unexpected character in input: '' (ASCII=5) state=1 in` and the ASCII changes to equal different values for each error, but all errors point to this line: `foreach(token_get_all($content) as $token) {`

Comment: This approach sucks.  The fact that it got 2 up votes was incredible and a poor vote from the people who did this.  No offense, but like I said, changing the filename from .xml to .php returns this as being TRUE!  I've never seen 1 instance where using the token_get_all() actually returned positive results.

Comment: My testcase was based on 3 .php-files, one which included `<?= 'hello' `, one with `<?php echo 'hello` and one with `hello`, they all returned correct values. If your xml file included `<?` then it's probably matched against an opening php-tag (which you'd hit with your regexp anyways). You could probably add more xml/zip/etc tests to blacklist.

Comment: My XML file had <?xml in it only.

Comment: For example: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>`  That's it, and this returned TRUE!

Comment: I really really would like to use this approach, but it's a shame it doesn't work. arggg.  Thanks anyways.

Comment: It will actually match anything containing those tags so it's just for whitelisting php and not blacklist anything else. Sorry bro. See http://php.net/manual/en/tokens.php

Comment: I don't even know what whitelisting and/or blacklisting even means... lol

Comment: Whitelisting = disallow everything but X, Y and Z; blacklisting = allow everything but X, Y Z. Think of spam filters with emails from your contacts (whitelisted) vs emails containing bad words (blacklisted). Or file inclusion: only allow your specified actions (whitelisting), vs disallowing every dangerous action (blacklisting, very hard to hit all those cases so whitelisting is a better choice here).

Answer (score 1):

```
\?>|<\?((?=php)|(?!\w))
```